# Export Site Templates, so its visible for Subsites too

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-template, sub-site

I`ve created a site template at the Parent level of SharePoint 2013 Intranet.
While creating a new subsite.
I can see the Site Template if I am accessing the following url: https://sharepoint.example.com/_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx

Please suggest how to have the site visible from Child sites as well.
Let say, if I`m creating a subsite within a child site then the url should even show the site template under custom template?

Subsite create request url:
https://sharepoint.example.com/projects/_layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx

Inshort, how can I export the Site Template to be visible from Subsite as well?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you specify the site templates:
Site Settings:PAGE LAYOUT AND SITE TEMPLATE

```
https://sharepoint.example.com/_layouts/15/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx
```